# UNIQUE KEY in any order

Tags: php, mysql, unique-key

I am using UNIQUE KEY for MYSQL for one table. However, I have a table which has "user1,user2". I created a UNIQUE KEY but the problem is I want the UNIQUE KEY to act whether "user1==user1 && user2==user2" OR "user1==user2 && user2==user1"

```
user1     user2
----------------
user1     user2
```

OR

```
user1     user2
----------------
user2     user1
```

How to achieve that UNIQUE KEY in mySQL?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you're overcomplicating a straightforward matter. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Don't think you'd be able to do this with standard SQL functionality. `(a,b)` is completely different from `(b,a)` as far as SQL is concerned and wouldn't count as a duplicate. You might be able to fake it using an 'on before' trigger for update/insert to catch such bi-directional keys.

Comment: Simple solution: when inserting, always reorder so that user1 < user2.  Then it's not possible to insert both `(1,3)` and `(3,1)`

Comment: I just don't want to SELECT in my PHP, and then do the check in PHP. I thought if this is doable in mySQL, then it is faster and easier. This applies to 30 tables in my database. It is for an invitation system: User1 adds User2 OR User2 adds User1 (I have them that way in many places of the code). So in the database, user1->user2 has a meaning, and user2->user1 has a meaning, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only do it if you also enforce another rule:

```
user1 < user2
```

Then you know that the UNIQUE constraint will meet your requirements.  (Or, conversely, `user1 > user2`; it doesn't matter which as long as you are self-consistent.)

Otherwise, as pointed out in the comments, the permutation '(b,a)' is different from '(a,b)' and the unique constraint will not enforce the uniqueness you want.